# What does the end of sentence "eh" tag mean in Canadian English?

Tags: canadian-english

What does the end of sentence *eh* tag mean in Canadian English? It seems like it should mean something. In other languages, final tags can indicate questions or other things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use it to mean "okay?" or "right?" or "do you not agree with me?" All more-or-less the same, acha?

Comment: Or it can just mean *"What have you got to say to that?"*, as in ["How you like them apples? Eh?"](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=mzwKVNob5lkC&pg=PA144&dq=%22like+them+apples%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=shwcT_KjAovb8QPLn_SQCw&ved=0CE4Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22like%20them%20apples%22&f=false)

Comment: Absolutely. Not one of my idioms, but quite common.

Comment: It's definitely one of mine - despite my mother constantly intoning *"'ay is for 'orses!"* throughout my youth! :)

Answer (score 4):

It's a Canadian, not American usage, but I've always considered it the "Anglo" equivalent of the French "n'est-ce pas?" which translates loosely into "isn't it so?"

Comment: He never said it was American.

Comment: @Mahnax: But I am American (for full disclosure).

Comment: How do you know that it is British?

Comment: I suppose, maybe it's used in the North of England? "What's all that about, eh, lad?" although that seems a bit of a stretch

Comment: This is a really, really common Canadian mannerism. I've met Canadians that do this genuinely, that do this in jest, and it is a what comedians seize on when imitating Canadians. I just have never lived in Canada (or along the Canada-US border), so I'm not sure what it means.

Comment: @Tom: if you removed the part about British/American, your answer would be just right (and then might get votes).

Comment: @Mitch: Changed "British" to "Canadian." I honestly thought the English used it also, but maybe not.

Comment: It's bog-standard British usage. If Canadians also say it, we didn't get it from them - they got it from *us*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: What's 'bog-standard'? I'm guessing it's not the Queen's English (but from what I hear the Queen's ain't it either).

Comment: @Mitch: Sorry - I was really aiming my comment more at Matt Эллен, who being UK-based would understand it. *Bog -standard* is another standard British expression meaning - well, "standard". I honestly don't know where the "bog" bit comes from, but it's very common in slightly down-market spoken usage. You wouldn't disagree with that Matt, eh?